# MFC MDI Toggling a tab in the output window without having to restart (in my case)

Tags: c++, tabs, visual-studio-2017, mfc

So I'm using the MFC wizard created output pane and everything works as I want it. What I'm trying to figure out is how to hide/show a specific tab with the user selecting it from the menu. I have two tabs, one is status, one is debug...I have a user menu option to turn the Debug on/off and I do this by using a switch using the registry to track the state of whether to draw it on the app start. I would like to be able to just turn the tab on and off without having to restart.

```
int COutputWnd::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CDockablePane::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    CRect rectDummy;
    rectDummy.SetRectEmpty();

    // Create tabs window:
    if (!m_wndTabs.Create(CMFCTabCtrl::STYLE_FLAT, rectDummy, this, 1))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create output tab window\n");
        return -1;      // fail to create
    }

    // Create output panes:
    const DWORD dwStyle = LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL;

    if (!m_wndOutputBuild.Create(dwStyle, rectDummy, &m_wndTabs, 2) ||
        !m_wndOutputDebug.Create(dwStyle, rectDummy, &m_wndTabs, 3))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create output windows\n");
        return -1;      // fail to create
    }   

    UpdateFonts();

    CString strTabName;
    BOOL bNameValid;

    // Attach list windows to tab:
    bNameValid = strTabName.LoadString(IDS_STATUS_TAB);
    ASSERT(bNameValid);
    m_wndTabs.AddTab(&m_wndOutputBuild, strTabName, (UINT)0);

    // Enable debug tab if user sets it in settings
    int EnableDebugTab = AfxGetApp()->GetProfileInt(_T("Settings"), _T("EnableDebugTab"), 0); //Get value from registry
    if (EnableDebugTab == TRUE)
    {
        bNameValid = strTabName.LoadString(IDS_DEBUG_TAB);
        ASSERT(bNameValid);
        m_wndTabs.AddTab(&m_wndOutputDebug, strTabName, (UINT)1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried:

```
m_wndOutputDebug.ShowWindow(FALSE);
```

but that didn't work.

```
m_wndOutputDebug.EnableWindow(FALSE);
```

That didn't work either.

I know tabs can be turned on and off, I just don't understand the mechanism to turn show and hide the debug tab.

What is the best way to handle this task?

---

## EDIT

So following IInspectable's comment, I was trying to show/hide the tab without destroying the tab data, ok, no worries....I had the wrong expectation of what I was trying to achieve.... I reworked debug tab to always start for testing like:

```
bNameValid = strTabName.LoadString(IDS_STATUS_TAB);
ASSERT(bNameValid);
m_wndTabs.AddTab(&m_wndOutputBuild, strTabName, (UINT)0);

bNameValid = strTabName.LoadString(IDS_DEBUG_TAB);
ASSERT(bNameValid);
m_wndTabs.AddTab(&m_wndOutputDebug, strTabName, (UINT)1);
```

adding:

```
m_wndTabs.RemoveTab(1);
```

This works as it always removes the debug tab...great!..but....

Knowing that worked...  `m_wndTabs.RemoveTab(1);` is commented out and added to a new function below.

The tab code lives in `COutputWnd`, I am calling this new function a menu item from my application.cpp via the message map:

```
ON_COMMAND(ID_SETTINGS_DEBUG_TAB, &COutputWnd::OnDebugTabShow)
```

added this function in `OutputWnd.cpp`:

```
void COutputWnd::OnDebugTabShow()
{
    m_wndTabs.RemoveTab(1); //exact code from on create that works there in test
}
```

I've commented out `m_wndTabs.RemoveTab(1);` in the oncreate (since I know it works there as a test)... when I debug and the `OnDebugTabShow()` is called... I get a

> Exception thrown: read access violation.
> `this->m_wndTabs`. was `nullptr`.

I'm not clear why the pointer is null since it is built and loaded.

Just need help sorting that bit out.

Comment: Since you're adding tabs with `AddTab` would it not be plausible to remove tabs with `RemoveTab`?

Comment: I was looking at it wrong..I have edited my post, got it working but having a NULL pointer issue that I am unclear how to fix.

Comment: Why not use `ShowTab()`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcbasetabctrl-class#showtab

Comment: I was looking for an example on how to implement it, read the doc...couldn't find a good code example of how it should look..I'll have another look at it.

Comment: I was able to implement ShowTab, .... m_wndTabs.ShowTab(1, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE);..., but getting the same pointer error, so clearly I am doing something wrong acting on the output pane tab. ugggh.

Comment: I'm lost, I can't figure out why I keep getting a NullPtr, anyone have any thoughts? I'm sure it is something simple, I just can't see past it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to Remove and add Tab. Show/Hide Tab using ShowTab() is suitably.
Here the example with ShowTab. Because the Tab can dymamically be moved anywhere, you must search the desired Tab for sure.

```
void COutputWnd::OnOutputtabsDebug()
{
  // Toggling OutputTab
  CString strDebugLabelShould;
  strDebugLabelShould.LoadString(IDS_DEBUG_TAB);

  CString strLabelIs;
  int nMax = m_wndTabs.GetTabsNum();

  for (int nId = 0; nId < nMax; nId++)
  {
    m_wndTabs.GetTabLabel(nId, strLabelIs);
    if (strLabelIs == strDebugLabelShould)
    {
        // found
        CWnd* pWnd = m_wndTabs.GetTabWnd(nId);
        BOOL bShow = !pWnd->IsWindowEnabled();

        m_wndTabs.ShowTab(nId, bShow);   // Toggle
        pWnd->EnableWindow(bShow);  
        break;                          
    }
  }
}
```

Command forward routing to COutputWnd
Since the MFC Command Routing does not this for you, must add the handler in Mainframe (or View) and forward it manually, example like this

```
  ON_COMMAND(ID_OUTPUTTABS_DEBUG, &CMainFrame::OnOutputtabsDebug)

void CMainFrame::OnOutputtabsDebug()
{
    m_wndOutput.OnOutputtabsDebug();
}
```

Comment: I plugged this in, compiled, debugged it up to `int nMax`, as soon as I step over (F10), it crashes with the same error I've been seeing: `Exception thrown: read access violation.
this->m_wndTabs. was nullptr.`

Comment: Here is the state of the auto watch just prior to me stepping over it and causing the exception: `CMFCBaseTabCtrl = {hWnd=0x00000000 <NULL>}`

Comment: Added note...I copied the function to `oncreate` and stepped through it....works exactly as expected. It seems the root of the problem is that the `CMFCTabCtrl m_wndTabs;` object is `NULL` when called from Application.cpp's handler, but not sure how to fix.

Comment: I have tested this, this works for me. If you have a NULL-Pointer, then there is something wrong happen before. Check it, or better do it in a new ,fresh SampleProject, as you have modified a lot with side-effects.

Comment: Ok, I built a new sample project, plugged in the function. I get a nullptr there also...this means I'm doing it wrong. So, in the view menu, I have an menu item called `junk`. What and where should the message handler `ON_COMMAND(ID_VIEW_JUNK, OnOutputtabsDebug)` be in? I've been told above Application.cpp is wrong, but if I put it `ON_COMMAND(ID_VIEW_JUNK, OnOutputtabsDebug)` in COutputWnd, the menu item disables....how are you calling the function `OnOutputtabsDebug()`? I think that is where I am going wrong. TY.

Comment: Yes, the MFC command routing [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/command-routing?view=msvc-160) does not this forward automatically to the Output Panes, you have to forward it manually to this COutputPane. I have added the handler in the mainframe and simple forward it to the COutputPane.

Comment: BINGO: Nailed it...That was the piece I was missing, got it working and NOW I understand what both you and Vlad were driving at. As FYI, I'm not a Software Engineer, I'm a Hardware EE Engineer & know enough to be dangerous...and started with someone else's code and adding GUI improvements. This really helped...THANK YOU! ... Chris

Answer (score 0):

Re:

> The tab code lives in COutputWnd, I am calling this new function a menu item from my application.cpp via the message map:
>
> ON_COMMAND(ID_SETTINGS_DEBUG_TAB, &COutputWnd::OnDebugTabShow)

Do you have this `ON_COMMAND` macro in your `application.cpp`? That would be wrong!

In that case your application's `this` pointer would be used in the `COutputWnd::OnDebugTabShow()` (cast to `COutputWnd`), causing all kind of problems.

This should be in your view's message map.

Comment: ok this makes sense, and yes, your assessment of it is correct on the mechanism. I don't have a view message map, so that creates a problem and hence why I tried it this way.......(which isn't working). Confirmation of the issue, I kind of figured this might be problematic.

Comment: @Kittmaster Re: `I don't have a view message map, so that creates a problem` - why don't you create that message map?

Comment: I've been working with existing code, didn't think to make my own...so another message map with this single macro located in application.cpp to handle this? What would that look like? I think I have an idea...thanks!

Comment: @Kittmaster Re: `another message map with this single macro located in application.cpp` - I would put it in the view implementation file instead.

Comment: The files I have are application.cpp, mainframe.cpp, Childframe.cpp, OutputWnd.cpp .... without and mdi docs loaded...sorry for the 101 question...does view implementation fall in one of those 4 files? ty.

Comment: @Kittmaster I don't know the structure of YOUR project. A View is typically derived from `CView` class, or one of its specializations. You really need to read about `MFC`'s Document/View architecture.

Comment: Vlad, understood, and I'll certainly take that advice. Thank you for your guidance. Tom Tom above help bring my issue into focus and I can move forward. Best Regards.